# ruby function takes dictionary pointer as argument, why?

Tags: ruby, pointers

```
def to_json(*opts)
  {
    'json_class'   => self.class.name,
    'data' => { 'term' => @term,
                'command' => @command,
                'client' => client
              }
  }.to_json(*opts)
end
```

Why does this Ruby function takes a dictionary pointer `*opts` as an argument, instead of just `opts`? What's the benefit here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asterisk `*` in `*opts` is NOT a pointer (as in C/C++). There's no such concept of pointer in Ruby.

---

When defining a method, it's used for splatting. For example:

```
def foo(first, *rest)
  "first=#{first}. rest=#{rest.inspect}"
end

puts foo("1st", "2nd", "3rd")
# => first=1st. rest=["2nd", "3rd"]
```

---

When calling a method, it's used to expand the argument. For example:

```
arr = ["2nd", "3rd"]
bar("1st", *arr)
```

is equivalent to:

```
bar("1st", "2nd", "3rd")
```

Comment: Note that `*opts` appears in the question in both the method signature, but also in the call to `to_json`

Comment: @user12341234 Updated now.